# TWebBroker + Indy on Android

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-10-seattle

I know how it works on VCL and there is even an option for Firemonkey.Running the wizard for webbroker and selecting standalone and then firemokey it create an application that works on windows. There is no option to add Android platform.

However I wanted to have TWebBroker + Indy on Android.

Is it possible? Can I change the Wizard created sample for Firemoney (standalone) to be Android compatible? Otherwise is there another way?

Comment: If you edit the .dproj file's `<platforms>` tag to add a `<Platform value="Android">True</Platform>` value, you'll find the Android platform is added to your project. But if you try to compile the code for Android, you will also find that most of the library code that Webbroker app depends on, is not available for the Android platform. Why would it be? Webbroker is a server application type, and Android devices don't make good servers.

Comment: @nolaspeaker Plenty of Android applications have server code in them. The WebBroker units can be compiled for Android by including the path to the source: $(BDS)\source\internet.

Comment: @Dave Nottage. Of course it isn't that simple. I just tried it. I don't think the code made by the WebBroker Wizard can be made to just run on Android without modifications (has winapi, datasnap server units etc) But yes, I stand corrected then. It probably is possible to make a web server that runs on Android if you do it carefully yourself.

Comment: @nolaspeaker It's quite trivial to do actually, by starting a WebBroker console app. I was planning to write an article on how to do it, but haven't had the time as yet

Comment: @Dave Nottage. Noted. The question however, was about the app generated about the WebBroker Wizard starting with selecting Firemonkey as the target framework.

Comment: @Dave Nottage For sure I will anxious waiting for such article, specially if it includes android... :)  I am not looking to exclusively using the wizard, I thought that could be a good starting point since generates firemonkey code, however my goal is to have webbroker working on android.

Comment: @Eduardo Elias. I googled it and found some basic examples immediately. Here is [Creating simplest Web Server using Delphi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R64_n8vIrvg). There is no reason this wouldn't work on Android.

Comment: I haven't done an article as yet, however I've created a project on Github that might have you started. Sorry there's no doc as yet: https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/MultiPlatformWebServer

Comment: @Dave really great! Could you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it? Sure my question was around reusing the wizard created source, but the target is getting the webbroker to work and you gave me that direction. It will be useful for many ! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a project on Github that might have you started. Sorry there's no doc as yet:

https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/MultiPlatformWebServer